# Can't access errors when rendering a field individually

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In views.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # ...process form...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auctions:index'))
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auctions:create'))
```

In the template, doing `{{  form.fieldname  }}` renders the form field correctly. However, if I submit a value for this field that passes html validation but doesn't pass `is_valid()`, the error message doesn't render in the template even though I put `{{  form.fieldname.errors  }}`. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I realized I am just rendering an unbound form with the HttpResponseRedirect so I changed my code to this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    #...process form...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auctions:index'))
else:
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {'form': form})
```

And this works, however, it's not the best practice to use render() instead of HttpResponseRedirect() after a user submits a form right? Any way to get around this?

Comment: because  on errors i.e when form validation fails you have redirected to a different view 'auction:create' which I think uses different html.

Comment: @MahenderThakur Yes I just learned what "bound form" and "unbound form" means. How do I render the bound form?

Comment: Iterate over form object passed in template and each item would have `errors` method contaning list of all errors for that specific field. Please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: "I am just rendering an unbound form" - It’s meaningless to validate a form with no data

Comment: to render bound form .. first you need to create a Form object by passing your data to it i.e form= Form(your_data)

Comment: @MahenderThakur Yes, when I do form.is_valid(), and then pass that form to render(), it passes the bound form. This works and I am able to render the errors in my template. However, isn't is_valid supposed to do this automatically? From the django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-view): "We call the form’s is_valid() method; if it’s not True, we go back to the template with the form. This time the form is no longer empty (unbound) so the HTML form will be populated with the data previously submitted, where it can be edited and corrected as required."